# How to build a feature to a zip file using Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to export an Eclipse feature using Tycho, replacing the "Export Wizard" found on the Eclipse overview of the feature. The wizard gives the option for the export destination as a zip file. Is there a way to do the same with Tycho?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28739467/1523648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build a zip file with the feature and the feature's plug-ins, you need to add a module of the assembly packaging type `eclipse-repository` to your reactor:

- Add an `eclipse-repository` module with the same parent POM as the
  `eclipse-feature` module (in order to inherit the same [target
  platform configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform)).
- Create a `category.xml` file in the root of the new module with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <site>
      <feature id="todo.your.feature.id" />
  </site>
  ```
- Add the new module to your [root POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation).

Comment: Thank you that's very clear, the Tycho manual is a little obscure in it's explanation.

Comment: This is probably because the manual is trying to explain multiple things at once. This is a lot better in stackoverflow: clear, simple questions and clear, simple answers :-)